Posting parameters to a C# endpoint via axios in React
I am trying to send parameters to a 'Post' endpoint but cannot hit the endpoint unless the signature is blank.  Otherwise (as in the example below) I get an "Unsupported Media Type" error in the console.  I can see that the parameters are going through but how do I access them in the C# method?  What signature do I use in the method to have access to these values?
jsx:
  axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/cookie',
  data: JSON.stringify({ name: 'John', desc: 'Man' }),
  dataType: 'json'
  });

c#:
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class CookieController : ControllerBase
{
  [HttpPost(Name = "")]
   public void Post([FromBody] string data)
   {
    ... 
   }
}


Which parameters ? I don't see any parameters in your code, and can you be more specific what exactly is the issue ? is it signature blank or accessing body data ?

Well that's my question.   What parameters do I put in the signature of the C# method to access the 'name' and 'desc' parameters I am sending via the axios POST.  Accessing the body data as you put it.

You are sending it as JSON data so in your C# code it will be available as JSON string in data variable, you can print it to see the data. Next you can use a JSON deserializer to get individual key data

Base on which version of dot net you are using this might work var jsonObject = JsonNode.Parse(data).AsObject();

The code I posted does not hit the endpoint. It generates a 415 Error. The only way I can get it to hit the endpoint is a blank signature. –

jsx:
  axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/cookie',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  data: JSON.stringify({ name: 'John', desc: 'Man' }),
  dataType: 'json'
  });

The Javascript sends JSON data and the C# expects it as a DTO I called "CookieData" to suit the route:
c#:
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class CookieController : ControllerBase
{
    public class CookieData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Desc { get; set; }
    }
     
    [HttpPost(Name = "")]
    public void Post([FromBody] CookieData data)
    {


So how would I accomplish this?

Add the CookieData class to your project (in the same Namespace) or even add the class inside the Controller Class to start with to get it working. Then change the Post endpoints string arg to be a CookieData.

I'm still getting a 415: "Unsupported Media Type".  It does not hit the endpoint method

In the jsx,  url: '/cookie',, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },

Sorry but I just noticed that the parameters are now hard coded into the Post.  If I wanted to get them from the text input and send them as a React object, I assumed it was this:  data: JSON.stringify({ name: {name}, desc:{desc}})    but that produces a bad request.

or even this: JSON.stringify({post})   Because I set it this way...
const [post, setPost] = useState({
name: '',
desc:''
})

Hang on John, you're turning this into a chameleon question. If you want support for expansible JSON content you can use JObject but that's a different topic.
